# Responsive shop with multiple items. Item prices will depend on the size of the item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the options to a radio type thing. I also want the items to have different prices depending on the size of the item that will be purchased.

*eg:* Caffe Latte(small) will have be priced at 15 while Caffe Latte(Large) will be priced at 30

How should I do it?
Thank you very much for the help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="sbwadcss.css">

 <script type="text/javascript">
 
   var totalPrice=0;

  function AddItem()
  {
   var itemPrice = parseInt(0);
   var itemName = document.getElementById('itemName').value;
   var qty = document.getElementById('txtQty').value.trim();
   var subTotal = document.getElementById('subTotal').value;
  



   if (qty!="")
   {
    if (qty.match(/^[0-9]+$/))
    {

     if(itemName=="Caffe Latte")
      itemPrice = (19*qty);
     else if (itemName=="Cappuccino")
      itemPrice = (19*qty);
     else if(itemName=="Caffe Americano")
      itemPrice = (17*qty);
     else if(itemName=="Flat WHite")
      itemPrice = (15*qty);
     else
      itemPrice = (15*qty);



     document.getElementById("subTotal").value = itemPrice;


     totalPrice+=itemPrice;

     if(itemName=="Caffe Latte")
     {
      document.getElementById('iName').value += "\n" + "Caffe Latte" ;
      document.getElementById('price').value += "\n" + itemPrice;
      document.getElementById('qty').value +=  "\n" + qty;
      document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = totalPrice;
     }
     else if (itemName=="Cappuccino")
     {
      document.getElementById('iName').value += "\n"+ "Cappuccino";
      document.getElementById('price').value += "\n" + itemPrice;
      document.getElementById('qty').value += "\n" +qty;
      document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = totalPrice;
     }
     else if(itemName=="Caffe Americano")
     {
      document.getElementById('iName').value += "\n" + "Caffe Americano";
      document.getElementById('price').value += "\n" +itemPrice;
      document.getElementById('qty').value +="\n" + qty;
      document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = totalPrice;
     }
     else if(itemName=="Flat WHite")
     {
      document.getElementById('iName').value += "\n" + "Flat White";
      document.getElementById('price').value += "\n" +itemPrice;
      document.getElementById('qty').value +="\n" + qty;
      document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = totalPrice;
     }

     else
     {
      document.getElementById('iName').value +=  "\n" + "Espresso";
      document.getElementById('price').value +="\n" + itemPrice;
      document.getElementById('qty').value +="\n" + qty;
      document.getElementById('totalPrice').value = totalPrice;
     }
     
     
    }
    else
     alert("INVALID INPUT FOR QUANTITY! ");
   }
   else
    alert("INVALID INPUT FOR QUANTITY ! ");
  }

  function Payment()
  {

   var payment = document.getElementById('payment').value.trim();
   var totalPrice = document.getElementById('totalPrice').value;
  
   if (payment !="")
   {
    if (payment.match(/^[0-9]+$/))
    {
     if (totalPrice <payment)
     {
      var change = payment - totalPrice;

      document.getElementById('change').value= "Php " + change + ".00";
            totalPrice=0;
     }
     else
      alert("Invalid Amount Entered!!");
    }
    else
     alert("Invalid Amount Entered!! ");
   }
   else
    alert("No Amount Entered!!");
  }

  function NewTransaction(target1,target2,target3)
  {
   var OK = confirm("Do you want to make New Transaction? \n OK or CANCEL? ");

   if (OK==true)
    target1.value="";
    target2.value="";
    target3.value="";
    totalPrice=0;
    document.getElementById('iName').value ="";
    document.getElementById('price').value ="";
    document.getElementById('qty').value ="";
    document.getElementById('totalPrice').value ="";
    document.getElementById('payment').value="";
    document.getElementById('change').value="";
  }
 
 </script>
 
 </head>


 <body>
 <div id="form">
 
 <legend class="wrap"><h3></h3></legend>

 <h4>SALES TRANSACTION</h4>


 <div class="content">
 <div class="left">
 Item Name: 
 </div>

 <div class="right">
 <select id="itemName">
 <option selected disabled="disabled">SELECT ITEM</option>
 <option>Caffe Latte</option>
 <option>Cappuccino</option>
 <option>Caffe Americano</option>
 <option>Flat White</option>
 <option>Espresso</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>


 <div class="content">
 <div class="left">
 Quantity: 
 </div>

 <div class="right">
 <input type="text" id="txtQty">
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="content">
 <div class="left">
 Price:  
 </div>

 <div class="right">
 <input type="text" id="subTotal" disabled="disabled">
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="btnContent">
 <input type="button" value="ADD ITEM" onclick="AddItem()" style="background-color: grey; margin:3px; border-radius: 5px;">
 </div>
 <div class="btnContent">
 <a href="SBWAD.html"><input type="button" value="CANCEL" style="background-color: grey; margin:3px; border-radius: 5px;"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="btnContent">
 <input type="button" value="NEW TRANSACTION" onclick="NewTransaction(document.getElementById('itemName'),document.getElementById('txtQty'),document.getElementById('subTotal'))" style="background-color: grey; margin:3px; border-radius: 5px;">
 </div>
 </div>



 <div id="form2">
 
 <div class="content">
 <div class="inline-div">
    <p align="center">Item Name</p>
    <textarea cols="10" rows="10" class="inline-txtarea" id="iName" disabled="disable"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div class="inline-div">
 <p align="center">Price</p>
     <textarea cols="10" rows="10" class="inline-txtarea" id="price" disabled="disable"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div class="inline-div">
     <p align="center">Quantity</p>
     <textarea cols="10" rows="10" class="inline-txtarea" id="qty" disabled="disable"></textarea>
 </div>
 

 </div>


 <div class="btnContent" style="width: 180px; padding-top: 5px;">
  TOTAL PRICE:  
 <input type="text" id="totalPrice" disabled="disabled">
 </div>

 <div class="btnContent" style="width: 180px; padding-left: 18px; padding-top: 5px;">
 ENTER PAYMENT:
 <input type="text" id="payment">
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="button" value="SUBMIT PAYMENT" onclick="Payment()" style="background-color: grey; margin:3px; border-radius: 5px;">
 CHANGE :
 <input type="text" id="change" disabled="disabled">
 </div>
 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the price into an object and read it from there depending on selection of small vs. large.

```
var prices = {'small': 15, 'large': 30};
```